# TypeORM not using Entity metadata correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using Typescript + TypeORM on my project. Here's an entity definition:

```
@Entity({ name: 'city-listing' })
export class CityListing {
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'uuid', unique: true, generated: true })
  @Generated('uuid')
  id: string

  @Column('varchar')
  title: string
```

Whenever I instantiate a repo it looks like this:

```
const conn = await getConnection()
const repo = await conn.getRepository(CityListing)
const queryResult = await repo.findOne({ id: 'whatever_here' })
```

The repository defaults to the classname instead of the metadata. SQL Output ends up looking like this:

```sql
 'SELECT "CityListing"."id" AS "CityListing_id"...'
```

instead of

```sql
 'SELECT "city-listing"."id" AS "CityListing_id"...'
```

Any idea why? I'm using "reflect-metadata" as the first import on my app entry point, and migrations output the correct sql output when run from the CLI

Comment: please show the total sql generated, as there must be an ALIAS in the FROM clause. something like "FROM city-listing  "CityListing" ...."

Comment: Hey @Jerome, yes you're correct. The problem on my query was unrelated to the Table name. I kept getting "Cannot find column" and thought the problem was the column name (but it was just an alias)